# Count entries by time

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, date

I have the situation where I want to track how many entires have been submitted in a channel in the last month, the month before that and so on.

So if I would want two know how many entries have been submitted within a month two month ago (I'm not saying August on purpose because it is important that it is dynamic and not static), how would I be able to do that?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Query the database using SQL, using month as a parameter. Then count the results.

Comment: Edd, thanks for the fast reply. There is no standard ee channel entry parameter that would allow setting a timeframe?

Comment: Check devotee for plugins. I know of none but I would just whip up a quick sql query.